# System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' C#, beginner

Tags: c#

This is the problem:

```
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            int num, num1, num2, num3;
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a number");
            num = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            num1 = num + 1;
            num2 = num + 2;
            num3 = num + 3;

            // The following line throws the error
            Console.WriteLine("The next numbers are:{0}(1}{2}", num1, num2, num3);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I try to start, and it writes about the commented line:

> System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'

Comment: what are you inputing? that format string looks fine. i'm guessing its really happening on `int.Parse`

Comment: @DanielA.White I try to input a number, and then the output should be the 3 numbers after it.

Comment: @DanielA.White There's actually a typo there, as shown in the answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You line is incorrect formatted

```
Console.WriteLine("The next numbers are:{0}(1}{2}", num1, num2, num3);
                                           ^
```

Change it to `{`

You get the error because only *two* input brackets are specified, but you supply *three* parameters.

Comment: Klotser Oh yeah man guess I did not notice, thank you! btw, any of you got time to help me with basics and stupid questions like this in private maybe? THANKS.

Comment: So... this was a typo question, and should be closed as such instead of answered

Comment: Yeah sure I will close it after someone will maybe want to help me in private with basics like that? I hope that's allowed!

Answer (score 1):

`The next numbers are:{0}(1}{2}`

You misplaced a `{` as `(` at placeholder 1.

Answer (score 0):

To get rid of errors like this, for the future I recommend that instead of

```
Console.WriteLine("The next numbers are:{0}{1}{2}", num1, num2, num3);
```

you could make use of [interpolated strings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interpolation#C#) like this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"The next numbers are:{num1}{num2}{num3}");
```

which have two advantages:

- You can write all the arguments directly *into* the string
- The compiler will detect spelling errors, such as `{0}(1}{2}`